# XCode 13.1. Is it possible to take a screenshot of an XCUIElement that doesn't fit in screen?

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcuitest, xcuiscreenshot, xcuielement

I have a long table with multiple elements within.
Is is possible to take a "long" screenshot that will include all elements, not only current screen state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Xcode is a very unintelligent screenshot tool. You get what’s visible for the screen or element you call it on - no more, no less.

You have two options:

1. Write code to manually scroll your table a few cells at a time, take a screenshot, and stop when you reach the last element. This obviously results in many screenshots. I’ve not found a smart stitching application that can be run programmatically.
2. Invest in a third party visual testing framework such as [Applitools](https://applitools.com/). They do have this functionality. If you’re small enough or don’t plan on doing much with their software this can be as inexpensive as $free.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! 
I suspected that there is no native way to do it in XCTest(

Also, I suppose that I will try to reconsider our screenshot testing approach and avoid checking whole big elements at once.